# Dual BOOT Windows / Linux Some files disappears

Tags: partition, windows, shared-partition

I have 3 operating systems in my computer : Windows 10, Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS and ArchLinux. I use all of them for my different works.

I use a FAT partition to share data into the different operating system.
But some files disappears when I restart to change the OS.

That is my fstab configuration to mount the Windows partitions. The NTFS partition is mount in read-only. And the FAT partition is mount in read-write.

```
UUID=DDCE-3B7D                    /SHARED           vfat   rw,fmask=1117,dmask=0007,uid=1000,gid=1000,user          0 2
UUID=20F024C1F0249F52             /WIN              ntfs   ro,fmask=3337,dmask=2227,uid=1000,gid=1000,nofail,user   0 2
```

I don't understand why some files disappear when I restart ? Maybe there is a configuration which need to does in Windows?

Comment: Show us, give examples.

Comment: What happens if you reboot into same system?

Comment: I download a file whit Ubuntu. I want print it so I reboot and go to Windows and the file has disappear. And I don't think files disappear when I reboot on same OS.

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause of your problems, but if you dual (or triple) boot, make sure you have Windows 10 fast boot disabled.

Comment: I said that an example would be useful, you gave another explanation. (also please put new info into question).